# Displaying Full width and height in jquery mobile in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**Here is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loginProcess()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'loginProcess.php',
        data:
        {
            uname:$("#userName").val(),
            pass:$("#pass").val(),
            rem:$("#remVal").val()
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == 1)
            {
                location.href="home.php";
            }
            else
            {
                location.href="index.php";
            }
        }
        });
}
function ckLogin(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        loginProcess();
    }
}
```

```
      <li>
            <font size="1px"> Username: </font>
            <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value="kamalesh" onKeyUp="ckLogin(event);" required="required" />
      </li>

      <li>
          <font size="1px"> Password: </font>
          <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="kamalesh" onKeyUp="ckLogin(event);" required="required" />
      </li>

      <li>
            <span><font size="1px"> Remember me: </font></span>
            <select data-role=slider id="remVal">

              <option value=no> No </option>

              <option value=yes> Yes </option>

            </select>
      </li>

      <li><input type="button" value="LogIn" onClick="loginProcess();"/></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DeJzZ/210/

Comment: Ya so what should we do with your code?

Comment: i want to display it according to the window height and width....if you are opening it in mobile means it should get the height and width of the mobile and display as like the same height .......same as like for other devices also......

Comment: Explain it in your question, it will be closed soon, so if you explain, will cast a re open vote

Comment: u can check with this link http://jsfiddle.net/DeJzZ/210/

Comment: If fiddle is deleted, people won't get what you exactly want, explain it in your question, it's vague

Comment: nothing i just want to display the content based on device width & height ....

Answer (score 2):

Use this code snippet in the head tag

---

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```